# Where is properties menu in Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I am getting an error in Xamarin when building a release version.  I actually have never released code before, and i have no idea what im doing.  if you could tell me, i am getting this error but i do not know how to follow the instructions because my Visual Studio doesnt have a menu called properties

> Debug is not enabled in the current configuration. Please Start
>   Without Debugging or change it in Properties -> iOS Build.

Comment: right click on the iOS project in solution explorer and choose Options or Properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click to IOS project--> open Proprieties page and enabled debug for IOS